# Change range value in table partition

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning, toad, plsqldeveloper

I have a big table with partitions.
ex:

```
CREATE TABLE cust_order (
cust_id     NUMBER(10), 
start_date   VARCHAR2(25), 
amount_sold NUMBER(10,2))
PARTITION BY RANGE (START_DATE)
(  
PARTITION MAY VALUES LESS THAN ('20120601'),
PARTITION DEF VALUES LESS THAN(MAXVALUE));
```

I want to alter the table so that the `MAY` partition contains values less than '20120501' and that the data from '20120501' to '20120601' are stored in the `DEF` partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should always store dates in `DATE` columns.  Storing dates in a `VARCHAR2(25)` column is a recipe for problems down the line-- someone will inevitably insert a string that has an unexpected format.

Second, assuming that there are no partitions between the `MAY` and `DEF` partitions, you could split the `MAY` partition

```
ALTER TABLE cust_order
  SPLIT PARTITION may AT ('20120501')
   INTO( PARTITION may,
         PARTITION june_temp )
 UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
```

and then merge the `JUNE_TEMP` and `DEF` partitions

```
ALTER TABLE cust_order
  MERGE PARTITIONS june_temp, def
   INTO PARTITION  def
```

I'm not sure that I see the wisdom, however, in doing this...  A default partition should not generally store any data-- it's generally only there so that inserts don't error out if they have an unexpectedly large partition key.  So taking the data that is already in one partition and moving it into a default partition seems rather odd.  If you're just going to create a `JUNE` partition in the future, I'm not sure why you wouldn't just split the partitions into a `MAY` and `JUNE` partition.

Comment: Hello Justin, yes for 1) but this is how this implemented. I want to "split" the MAY partition in order that values less than 20120501 go to MAY and the ones that no longer fit that partition go to DEF.

Comment: @odew - Updated your question and my answer.